# How do I download files of big sizes from somewhere on the web to the web server with PHP?

Tags: php

How do I download files of big sizes from somewhere on the web to the web server with PHP? Also, what should be allowed on the server in order to make this happen? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need CURL module installed on PHP.

Then create a folder on the server to save the downloaded files and set write permissions so that the webserver can write to that folder. Then just modify this PHP-script to download whatever file you want, just change the URL and the target filename (my example downloads Opera 10 disk image for Mac):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.opera.com/download/get.pl?id=32242&location=238&nothanks=yes&sub=marine';
$filename = 'temp/opera.dmg';
$fp = fopen($filename,'w+');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

The CURLOPT_TIMEOUT sets the maximum time CURL can use to download the file, note also that if the downloads take long time to finish, you might need to modify the PHP execution timeout in php.ini.

Comment: 50 mins or secs?

Comment: How do I know how many secs it will need???

Comment: The timeout is in secs. And you just need to calculate the maximum time the download might take. Just estimate your download speed, divide the maximum filesize with that and add some for safety and that is the timeout value you need.

Comment: And what if I cut out the timeout option? Would it hurt?

Comment: Only 2M out 10M have been downloaded. 2M is set as upload_max_filesize in php.ini on the server. How to change?

Comment: upload_max_filesize should affect this at all, that deals with the maximum filesize you can upload to a PHP from a form on a webpage. And you can remote the timeout option, but that will just default it to some preset value. If you cannot change the php.ini, you can try changing the max_execution_time by set_time_limit(); -command.